# Primefaces MenuBar third item not clickable?

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a issue with JSF2+Primefaces Menubar.I am using Primefaces MenuBar [Here](http://www.askkuber.com/IndianStock/topStocks/Index_Movements)

But the third item of a menu item is not clickable i am not able find out what is the issue here. Or User is not able to click on third option on where there are more then 2 options in sub menu.
Example:- In menu if you will click on **Research** then you can not click on **Stock to Watch** item easily. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Subodh:I think it is browser issue.Because when I check this site in IE,I am click on Stock to Watch but in case of Mozilla it is not working.

Comment: Thanks you are right its a browser issue can you please tell me workaround with other browser also as we know Primefaces is browser compatible.

Comment: I askked Primefaces forum they are saying its not Browser issue but it is a Primefaces issue.